# is it possible to use @transactional annotation with a transaction opened by hand (spring/hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a spring application which works with hibernate and annotations.
I open a session by hand which is done like in this [How do I manually open a hibernate session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884423/how-do-i-manually-open-a-hibernate-session) stack overflow answer.

Now i want to use a method of a service in the method that opens the session itself. This service however is annotated with the transactional statement. Is it possible to tell the method to use the transaction i just opened by hand?

e.g.

```
@Transactional("TransactionManager")
class Service1  {

   public LazyObject someMethod();

}

class MetaService {

   @Autowired
   SessionFactory sf;

   Service1 s1;

   public someMethod() {
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();

        // tell this method to use s's transaction
        // without annotating someMethod() with @transactional
        LazyObject lo = s1.someMethod();

        for ( LazyAtt la : lo.getLazyAtt() ) {
            la.doSomething();
        }

        s.flush();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
   }
}
```

For those wondering why I want to do it, check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363634/how-to-open-two-sessions-in-one-function-in-hibernate-spring